# pgfgantt bar alignment off

Tags: pgfgantt, sharelatex

[image]

For some reason it looks like that, here is the code:

```
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{ganttchart}{28}{28}
    \gantttitle{2012}{12}
    \gantttitle{2013}{16} \\
    \gantttitle{October}{4}
    \gantttitle{November}{4}
    \gantttitle{December}{4}
    \gantttitle{January}{4}
    \gantttitle{February}{4}
    \gantttitle{March}{4}
    \gantttitle{April}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{Study previous code}{3}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Writing 1st rep.}{3}{4} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{4}\\
    \ganttbar{Writing 2nd rep.}{5}{7} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{7}\\
    \ganttbar{Writing research rep.}{6}{9} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{9}\\
    \ganttbar{Desktop application}{7}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Tablet application}{10}{15} \\
    \ganttbar{Connecting applications}{9}{19} \\
    \ganttbar{Writing 3rd rep.}{18}{20} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{20}\\
    \ganttbar{Data analysis tools}{19}{25} \\
    \ganttbar{Writing final report}{20}{28} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{28}\\
    \ganttbar{Writing 4th rep.}{21}{23} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{23}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
    \end{landscape}
```

That is the only code on the page for the chart. I've also started a new project on ShareLatex and it does the same thing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you turned your code snippet into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution where changes is shown by <---. Also, this solution uses `landscape` from `geometry`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{1}{28}  % <---
    \gantttitle{2012}{12}
    \gantttitle{2013}{16} \\
    \gantttitle{October}{4}
    \gantttitle{November}{4}
    \gantttitle{December}{4}
    \gantttitle{January}{4}
    \gantttitle{February}{4}
    \gantttitle{March}{4}
    \gantttitle{April}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{Study previous code}{3}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Writing 1st rep.}{3}{4} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{4}\\
    \ganttbar{Writing 2nd rep.}{5}{7} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{7}\\
    \ganttbar{Writing research rep.}{6}{9} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{9}\\
    \ganttbar{Desktop application}{7}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Tablet application}{10}{15} \\
    \ganttbar{Connecting applications}{9}{19} \\
    \ganttbar{Writing 3rd rep.}{18}{20} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{20}\\
    \ganttbar{Data analysis tools}{19}{25} \\
    \ganttbar{Writing final report}{20}{28} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{28}\\
    \ganttbar{Writing 4th rep.}{21}{23} 
    \ganttmilestone{}{23}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
%    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why I got the alignment problem in the first place?

Comment: The main source of error is {28}{28} used in the \begin{ganttchart}. Further, vgrid and hgrid is added too.